# WiFi constantly taking over control on my iMac

Tags: network, wifi, imac, ethernet

I am using an iMac Pro running 10.14.6. I am connected to the NAS with a 10Gbit network connection. When I go to transfer large files to the NAS I check iStats Menu and notice that the WiFi connection seems to take over the main network connection, which is significantly slower.

In System Preferences I have double checked the Service Order: [image]

But for some reason the iMac decides to ignore this order when copying large files. What can I do to hammer it in?  Besides turning WiFi off. I mainly use WiFi to enable unlock my Mac with my Apple Watch - which is very valuable to me.

Thanks
- Joseph

Comment: I faced the same situation, but I found the minor convenience of unlocking my phone with my watch too inconvenient to overcome, so I turned it off. I still have all my fingers, so the fingerprint sensor on my 2019 MBA works just as well.

Comment: I can totally understand. oh... how I wish that there would be an Apple Keyboard with Touch ID  Nice to know that I am not alone.